# heroku 404 with django on deploy from git

Tags: python, django, heroku, http-status-code-404

I am having the error 404 when i open or deploy my app on heroku on the logs it doesnt show an actual line of error, i have follow the guidelines on the heroku and still i dont get it , already done the debug and disable with the collectstatic , did the migrate and makemigrations , check wsgi according to the whitenoise recent version which is moving it from that file

my settings.py

```
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = '******'

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'buscador',
    'bootstrap4',
    'gunicorn',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = '*****.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = '******.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
        'LOGGING': {
            'version': 1,
            'loggers': {
                'djongo': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'propogate': False,                        
                }
            },
         },
        'NAME': '****',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://*****:*****@mongodb-cluster-us-east-1-yuln1.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        }
    }
} 


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]





LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)





MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/images'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")



STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','staticfiles'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
    # Add to this list all the locations containing your static files 
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'



django_heroku.settings(locals())
code here
```

my urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from buscador import views
from buscador.views import Inicio, Buscar
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from letmepark import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',Inicio.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('buscar',Buscar.as_view(), name='buscar'),

]

urlpatterns += patterns('',
 (r'^static/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
 )
```

and the console

```
2020-04-04T00:37:55.141677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=******.herokuapp.com request_id=59b48817-b964-4fde-a9a9-374b2d8f50eb fwd="88.17.242.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=258 protocol=https
2020-04-04T00:37:58.404890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=*****.herokuapp.com request_id=84fea6ba-281e-4556-83a3-40158a140beb fwd="88.17.242.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=258 protocol=https
2020-04-04T00:37:58.408848+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.94.34 - - [04/Apr/2020:00:37:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
```

my requiriment.txt

```
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
bson==0.5.8
dataclasses==0.6
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.10
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
djongo==1.3.1
dnspython==1.16.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
mongoengine==0.8.0
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
pymongo==3.10.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

i got my static,template and staticfiles on root, so i cant find a solutions been looking and nothing works for me so far, HELP :D

EDIT:

forgot to add mi Procfile

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn letmepark.wsgi
```

Comment: update the procfile and any suitable error trace

Comment: i did from procfile i didnt got any error

Comment: u could also put  `debug = True` ,  just to get some help from the debugging output, then turn it off back to `debug = False` .

Comment: okey will try the debug part